# Segmentation fault 11 when accessing linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm sure I've screwed up my pointers, or perhaps the initial `NULL`, but I can't figure it out.

I'm trying to write a linked list out to a text file:

```
write_out(node *ll){
    ofstream out;
    out.open("output.txt");
    if (!out.is_open()) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    cout << ll->value;

    //stuff to write out
}
```

and:

```
struct node {
    int value;
    node *next;
}
```

But the line `cout << ll->value` causes `Segmentation fault: 11`, I do not understand why however.

I've commented out the code I was actually doing to write out, as this is irrelevant, the issue is obviously with my (lack) of understanding how the above works.

I call `write_out(linkedlist)` where `node* linkedlist` points to the first node.

This happens after:

```
read_in(node *ll){
    ifstream data; //opened and checked open as above for out
    int v;
    ll = new node;
    node *tmp = ll;
    data >> tmp->value;
    while(data >> v){
        tmp->next = new node;
        tmp = tmp->next;
        tmp->value = v;
    }
    tmp->next = NULL;  //thanks @sharth
}
```

Which surely hasn't left `ll = NULL`?

Comment: Can you show the code where you call `write_out`? It sounds like `linkedlist` is a null or invalid pointer.

Comment: Erm, tougher than it sounds to show. I do `node* linkedlist = NULL`, then `read_in`, and then `write_out`. I'll post `read_in` above, in case that is leaving it as `NULL`.

Comment: Additionally to the other answers, I'm slightly concerned that the last node in your linked list has an undefined next pointer, when it should be explicitly null.

Comment: Thanks @sharth, will fix. For some reason, the (n-1)th `next` is null rather than pointing to the nth.. can you see why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
read_in(node *ll){
```

`ll` is a parameter passed *by value*. That means any changes to it inside `read_in` are only local to it and have no effect outside it. Therefore after `read_in` is done, the pointer to the head of your list is still `NULL` (assuming that's what you initialized the pointer with). Calling `write_out` with a `NULL` parameter therefore dereferences a NULL pointer, which will cause your SIGSEGV.

Comment: I initially tried to pass by reference `read_in(node &ll){`, but I couldn't figure out how to then do anything with `ll` that the compiler wouldn't complain about. Can I return the new value of `ll` instead, and assign it when called: `ll = read_in(ll)`?

Comment: Thanks. I have the same issue (at least now I know what it is!) now in that the (n-1)th does not point to the nth. All the others write out fine, but I can't see why?

Comment: @sharth has given a pointer about that in the comments, check it out.

Comment: I'm not seeing it, has it been deleted?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711537/segmentation-fault-11-when-accessing-linked-list/21711888?noredirect=1#comment32830718_21711537) it is.

Comment: Ah no that's not what I mean. I fixed that. @sharth was concerned that the nth item pointed to nowhere, but I didn't explicitly say this was `NULL`. This issue I am now having, is that the (n-1)th doesn't point to that nth.

Answer (score 0):

I can guess that the problem is in the function where you add new nodes to the list.

I think you do something similar

```
void add_node( node *n, int value );

node *linkedlist = NULL;

add_node( linkedlist, somevalue );
```

In this case any changes of linkedlist inside the function does not influence the original object linkedlist. So it will still be equal to NULL. So when you try to output the list and use

```
cout << ll->value;
```

ll is equal to NULL.

Comment: Ah! This could be it - can you verify from my `read_in` as supplied?

Comment: @Ollie Ford You should write the function correctly. Either it has to retrurn the modified linkedlist pointer or the corresponding parameter has to be defined as pointer to pointer to node or reference to pointer to node.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple example to added what @Michael Foukarakis pointed out

```
#include<iostream>

void this_dont_change_ptr(int* a, int val){
    a = new int;
    *a = val;   
}

void this_changes_ptr_itself(int** a, int val){
    *a = new int;
    *(*a) = val; 
}

int main(){

    int *my_ptr = NULL;
    this_dont_change_ptr(my_ptr, 5);

    if(my_ptr == NULL){
        std::cout << "In fact, ptr is still NULL" << std::endl;
    }

    // What I do with allocated memo??

    // grants that my_ptr is NULL again
    my_ptr = NULL;  
    this_changes_ptr_itself(&my_ptr, 5);
    if(my_ptr == NULL){
        std::cout << "MUST never get here!" << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Now we have a new value " << *my_ptr << std::endl;    
    }

    delete my_ptr;  

    return 0;
}
```